# How to display Listview Header dynamically using Base Adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have to show the contents of 6 different tables of different column numbers through a Listview using a Base Adapter. I'm able to achieve this but now I also want to show the header at the top of the ListView which will tell the name of the Column and I want to do this within the ListView, meaning I don't want to add any extra views for the footer because I would have to create 6 different views for different headers.

Sorry for the long codes.

Here is my Custom Adapter class in which only one case  is considered

```
package com.example.bilalrafique.bloodbankmanagementsystem;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<ListType> entriesList;
    boolean header=true;
public CustomAdapter(Context context,List<ListType> entriesList) {
    this.context=context;
    this.entriesList=entriesList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return entriesList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return entriesList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return entriesList.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v=null;
    if(entriesList.get(position).getTableType().equals("Dnr")){
        v=View.inflate(context,R.layout.layout_lv_dnrentry,null);
        TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEId);
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEName);
        TextView age = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEAge);
        TextView gender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEGender);
        TextView bloodGroup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEBloodGroup);
        if(position==0 && header==true){
            id.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
            name.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
            age.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
            gender.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
            bloodGroup.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
            header=false;
        }
        else {
            id.setText(String.valueOf(entriesList.get(position).getId()));
            name.setText(String.valueOf(entriesList.get(position).getName()));
            age.setText(String.valueOf(entriesList.get(position).getAge()));
            gender.setText(String.valueOf(entriesList.get(position).getGender()));
            bloodGroup.setText(String.valueOf(entriesList.get(position).getBloodGroup()));
        }
    }
return v;
}
}
```

This is DonorView class

```
package com.example.bilalrafique.bloodbankmanagementsystem;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class DonorView extends Activity {
List<ListType> entriesList;
Cursor dCur;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_dnr_view);
    dCur=MainActivity.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Donor",null);
    entriesList=new ArrayList<>();
    ListType.populateList(this,entriesList, dCur,"Donor");
    ListView lvDnr=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvDnrView);
    CustomAdapter lvAdapter=new CustomAdapter(this,entriesList);
    lvDnr.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
}
}
```

This is layout_dnrview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvDnrView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is layout_lv_dnrentry.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/lvDnr_linear">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Id"
    android:id="@+id/dnrEId"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="235dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/dnrEName"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Age"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/dnrEAge"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="M/F"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/dnrEGender"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bld Grp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/dnrEBloodGroup"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now the problem is that it skips the first row in the Database table and in place of that row it shows the header then beneath that header it starts showing 2nd, 3rd and next rows. But I want it to show the header at the top and then start showing the actual table.
And again, I can't create different layouts for different headers. Some would contain 6 columns some would 4 and some would 3.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to add a addHeader method in the Donor view Class.

created this method in the Donor view class

```
public View donorHeader(Context c){
    View v=View.inflate(c,R.layout.layout_lv_dnrentry,null);
    TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEId);
    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEName);
    TextView age = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEAge);
    TextView gender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEGender);
    TextView bloodGroup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dnrEBloodGroup);
    id.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
    name.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
    age.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
    gender.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
    bloodGroup.setBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
    return v;
}
```

and in the DonorView onCreate method change the code to `

```
CustomAdapter lvAdapter=new CustomAdapter(this,entriesList);
    lvDnr.addHeaderView(donorHeader(this));
    lvDnr.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
```

Now remove the nested if,else in the Custom adapter getView method.